# How to do Oracle (+) left join query for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

We are using Oracle 11.
When doing LEFT JOIN like below, the result of the query is 11,053 rows

```
…LEFT JOIN LIQ ON LIQ.ID = SEC.ID AND LIQ.UPD_DT  >= '08-JAN-19'
WHERE …
```

But, when doing LEFT JOIN using (+) like below, the result of the query is 10,136 rows

```
...FROM SEC, LIQ
WHERE LIQ.ID (+)= SEC.ID AND LIQ.UPD_DT  >= '08-JAN-19'
```

How can I use (+) with multiple columns ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't try - just use the proper join syntax. If that works why would you want to revert to the ancient Oracle-only syntax that even they don't recommend you use?

Comment: The reason is because you are missing the second (+) in your second query, so you have effectively turned the second query into an inner join. However, as Alex has said, don't use the old style; use the ANSI syntax, for clarity and ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to just include the `(+)` for both terms:

```
WHERE LIQ.ID (+) = SEC.ID AND LIQ.UPD_DT (+) >= '08-JAN-19'
```

although you appear to be comparing a date with a string, relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings; if so convert it or use a date literal:

```
WHERE LIQ.ID (+) = SEC.ID AND LIQ.UPD_DT (+) >= DATE '2019-01-08'
```

But changing from 'modern' (post-1992) ANSI join syntax to Oracle's ancient and proprietary syntax seems like a very odd thing to want to be doing. Even [Oracle recommend](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354) you use don't use their syntax:

> Oracle recommends that you use the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator `(+)` are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax:
>   ...

(although there are still a lot of code examples in their docs which do, unhelpfully...)

There used to be some bugs around ANSI syntax, and there may still be rare cases where you see different behaviour or can't use the new syntax; but it's unlikely, and if you have a query that works there doesn't seem to be any advantage in regressing to the old ways.

Comment: Actually there are still edge cases, certainly in 11g and 12c, where the ANSI 92 syntax creates odd execution paths, However, they are very much edge cases and I think the clarity of the explicit join syntax vastly outweighs the risk of an inefficient access path.

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding a note about that *8-)

Comment: Thank you all ! Alex Poole's and Boneist answer solved it.
I also don't want to use (+) in my query, I prefer to use LEFT JOIN syntax. Unfortunately, the application that I need to put this query on doesn't understand LEFT JOIN, and so I need to put all the JOINs in there WHERE clause :(